# How to Implement Formula into Excel cells using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I want to implement the following formula in to Excel cells

```
IF(OR(D12>0,C13=""),"",MAX(SUM($C$12:C13)-$D$9,0))
```

(once formula is applied I should get following result (formula implemented manually):

[image]

so i wrote simple macro as below , but unable to implement formula , formula retuns value as "true"

```
Sub adjustoldbills()

lastRow_sht4 = Sheet4.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sheet4.Cells(12, 11) = ""

For i = 1 To lastRow_sht4 - 10
    If Sheet4.Cells(11 + i, 1) <> "" Then
        '=MAX(SUM($C$12:C15)-$D$9,0)
        Sheet4.Cells(12, 4).Formula = "=MAX(SUM($C$12:C" & 12 & ")-$D$9,0)"
        Sheet4.Cells(11 + i, 4).Formula = "=(if(or(D" & 11 + i > 0 & ",C" & 12 + i & "=" & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ")," & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & "," & "MAX(SUM($C$12:C" & 12 & i & ")-$D$9,0)"
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

i am getting wrong result after implemented formula via vba macro as in this image:

[image]

how to implement formula and get value as expected.

Comment: have you tested my answer below ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd go another way, with no loops and exploiting [`SpecialCells()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx) method of `Range` object

```
Option Explicit

Sub adjustoldbills()

    With Sheet4
        .Range("D12").FormulaR1C1 = "=MAX(RC[-1]-R9C4,0)" 
        With .Range("A13", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
            With .Offset(, 2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                .Offset(, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[-1]C>0,"""",MAX(SUM(R12C[-1]:RC[-1])-R9C4,0))"
                With .Areas(.Areas.Count)
                    .Offset(, 1).Cells(.Rows.Count).Offset(1).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R[-1]C>0,"""",MAX(SUM(R12C[-1]:RC[-1])-R9C4,0))"
                End With
            End With
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you verymuch , i am getting proper result now thanks once again

Comment: you are welcome. Then please mark answer as accepted by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. thank you

Comment: Would the brave downvoter kindly explain why he didn't like this answer and give suggestions as how to improve it? Or remove the down vote if he was wrong. Thank him

Answer (score -1):

When trying to convert long formulas to VBA try using a `String` variable to help you test it.

```
 Dim FormulaStr              As String

 FormulaStr = "=IF(OR(D" & 11 + i & ">0,C" & 12 + i & "=" & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ")," & _
      Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ",MAX(SUM($C$12:C" & 12 + i & ")-$D$9,0))"
 Debug.Print FormulaStr
```

Then, in the immediate window you will get:

```
=IF(OR(D12>0,C13=""),"",MAX(SUM($C$12:C13)-$D$9,0))
```

which is the formula you want to convert to VBA.

Now all you need to do is to add the line below:

```
 Sheet4.Cells(11 + i, 4).Formula = FormulaStr
```

If you want to skip the String variable, you can just replace your line of

```
Sheet4.Cells(11 + i, 4).Formula = "=(if(or(D" & 11 + i > 0 & ",C" & 12 + i & "=" & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ")," & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & "," & "MAX(SUM($C$12:C" & 12 & i & ")-$D$9,0)"
```

to:

```
Sheet4.Cells(11 + i, 4).Formula = "=IF(OR(D" & 11 + i & ">0,C" & 12 + i & "=" & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ")," & Chr(34) & Chr(34) & ",MAX(SUM($C$12:C" & 12 + i & ")-$D$9,0))"
```

Comment: just like @user3598756 wrote, "Would the brave downvoter kindly explain why" ?